# Distribute value equally among two numbers

Tags: c

I have three fields A, B, C. I need to make sum of A and  B always equals to C.

Requirements:
1.) if sum ( a,b ) < C: then distribute the diff evenly among A, B such that A + B = C

2.) If sum ( a, b ) > C, then subtract the values from A, B such that A+B = C . A, B should never be negative.

```
int main ( )
{
    int a , b, c;

    scanf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c );
  
    distrbute_c_among_a_b ( &a, &b, &c )

}
void distrbute_c_among_a_b( int a , int b, int c )
{
  // How to do this..
   if ( c >= ( a +  b) )
   {
        
        
    }//
        
   if ( c < (a+ b) )
    {
        
     // ??
     }
            
            }
```

Comment: Can you explain an algorithm for solving these two cases in words? Then we can help you turn that into code. As it stands it looks like you're asking us to do your assignment for you.

Comment: OT `c >=` ---> `c >`

Comment: You really ought not use scanf to pass parameters, since that what the arguments to `main` are for.  But if you're going to use scanf, you need to use it correctly.  You must pass `&a`, `&b`, and `&c`, and you *must* check the return value.

Comment: And, the signature for `distribute_c_among_a_b` is wrong.  You have the right idea to pass `&a`, etc. when you call it, but you must declare it to accept the right type. eg `void distribute_c_among_a_b(int *a, int *b, int *c)` (although you do not need to pass &c, since c is not modified by the function.)

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to be

```
void distrbute_c_among_a_b( int* a , int* b, const int c )
```

as you want to be able to change `a` and `b`. And call it like:

```
distrbute_c_among_a_b(&a , &b, c);
```

Here is a way to solve half of the problem

```
if ( c > (*a + *b) )
{
    int diff = c - *a + *b;
    *a = *a + diff/2 + (diff & 1);
                     // ^^^^^^^^
                     // If diff is odd, it adds 1 more two a
    *b = *b + diff/2;
    return;
 }
```

The other half is pretty similar - except you also you need to make sure that `a` and `b` doesn't end up being negative numbers.

And for `scanf`:

First you need to pass pointers - like:

```
scanf("%d %d %d\n", &a, &b, &c );
```

but also: **Always** check the return value

```
if (scanf("%d %d %d\n", &a, &b, &c ) != 3)
{
    // Input error
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: How about the case when ( a + b ) <= C ??

Comment: @user2618994 I'll leave that for you an an exercise. The code above should give you the hints needed.

Comment: The case that you described is working and thanks a lot for that. I am stuck when again when the ( a+ b ) < = C with a and b being negative at times. Could you describe this more

Comment: @user2618994 To start with you can forget about "not being negative". So calculate diff in a sligthly other way and instead of adding `diff/2`, subtract it. Once you have that code running, you add code for handling negative values.

Comment: if its negative, then we have to subtract the whole diff from a single number.

Comment: @user2618994 The missing case is: `c < (*a + *b)`. So consider `a = 5`, `b = 7` and `c = 10`. How will you change `a` and `b` to make `a + b = c` ?

Comment: subtract 1 from each..I get the logix, but failing to write in fewer logics in code. I would like to minimize code lines as much as possible

Comment: @user2618994 just do like I did but calculate `diff` a little differently and subtract instead of adding.